# MySQL: Distance between two people in a same area

Tags: mysql

Using Haversine formula gives the distance between two points as a bird flying over the building, which i know how to use. But i want to calculate a road distance between two points in a mysql query. How can i do that?

This is a location table:

```
place|latitude|longitude
a    |78.2252 |37.3365
b    |78.235  |25.3364
```

Now, i have to find near places from my database with respect to current latitude and longitude from GPS.

Comment: You'll have to use an API, unless you have all the data. Google has a distance matrix API.

Comment: have you some sample data ???

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338167/sql-query-of-haversine-formula-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query of Haversine formula in SQL server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338167/sql-query-of-haversine-formula-in-sql-server)