# How to apply Haversine Formula with another condition?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

Say I have these two tables:

**the_schedule_table:**

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+
| id  | start_date          | end_date            | latitude  | longitude  |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+------------------------+
| 1   | 2017-07-17 12:00:00 | 2017-07-17 14:00:00 | 42.330078 | -83.045074 |
| 2   | 2017-07-17 8:00:00  | 2017-07-17 11:00:00 | 42.330380 | -83.037918 |
| 3   | 2017-07-17 13:00:00 | 2017-07-17 15:00:00 | 42.351314 | -83.067020 |
| 4   | 2017-07-17 11:00:00 | 2017-07-17 13:00:00 | 42.474879 | -83.241544 |
| 5   | 2017-07-17 15:00:00 | 2017-07-17 17:00:00 | 42.271986 | -83.742137 |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+-----------+------------+
```

**teams:**

```
+-----+--------+------+
| id  | member | mate | 
+-----+--------+------+
| 1   | 1      | 2    | 
| 2   | 1      | 3    | 
| 3   | 1      | 4    | 
| 4   | 1      | 5    | 
| 5   | 2      | 1    | 
+-----+--------+------+
```

And then, say `Id = 1` calls the API with a specific `start_date|end_date` and `latitude|longitude`, call them *target*, and wants to know, who are the mates that are within X distance from his data, and their `start_date->end_date` DOES NOT overlap with his.

For the overlap I can do this: [(StartA > EndB) and (EndA < StartB)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964/5890227)

And for the distance I need to combine this: [SQL query of Haversine formula](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338205/5890227)

How do I write this sql statement?

**EDIT:**
I have the overlapping part and I tested it and it gave correct results:

```
// query overlapped activites - based on data time
const myQuery = 
    "SELECT * FROM schedule " +
    "WHERE start_date > '" + toMySqlFormat(target_end_date) +
    "' AND '" + toMySqlFormat(target_start_time) + "' > end_date";
```

Now I get lat,lng and ID, do I check distances then? and finally who are the mates? or do I start by finding mates, then overlaps, then distance?.. etc. I think I am starting right, but I want to optimize it so it is fastest possible. basically 3 conditions:

- they are mates (different table)
- their time does not overlap (same table)
- they are within x distance (same table)

The struggle is real.

Comment: What have you try it? What problems you have? Because looks like you have all the parts already.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I am poor with SQL conditional statements, this one is a little complex for me. I have it working but in code - I am switching to sql operations instead of code

Comment: Yeah, it seems like you've figured out all the hard bits :-)

Comment: @Strawberry the attached Haversine has different tables structures, and the overlapping is not SQL. No I did not figure out the hard part which is the one sql statement that does all on my table structure :)

Comment: I see, But can you write the date overlap version at least?? Show us something so we can guide you. Otherwise looks like a "do my job" question even when I can see you did some research. You will learn more by trying than by let other do the job.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I thought of keeping it clean as I don't want (maybe) for others to use my humble select statement which part of the answer. I added it

Comment: That is much better, that give me the idea of where I can help. Also tell me you need to learn about parametrized query to avoid sql injection attacks https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have 4 parameters @member_id, @start_date, @end_date, @distance

You need to use `JOIN` to find out the mates of `member = 1`

Then you can find out if those mates doesn't overlap with the dates. The conditional in your link indicate overlap, you want the inverted conditional so add `NOT`.

Finally use check if the result of the formula is less than @distance

```
 SELECT *
 FROM member M 
 JOIN the_schedule_table S
   ON M.mate = S.id
 WHERE NOT (S.start_date < @end_date AND S.end_date > @start_date)
   AND ( { Haversine formula } ) < @distance
   AND M.member = @member_id
```

Comment: looks nice, can you add some brief comments for each line please? like what is `FROM member m`? I usually know what is `FROM mytable`, and thanks I am testing it :)

Comment: Looks like you should try a tutorial to get the basics first. Check this one https://www.w3schools.com/sql/default.asp. That `M` is called an alias so the code is more easy to read.

Comment: Roger. Thanks for the links