# Finding nearest places using point datatype and st_distance_sphere in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, geospatial, latitude-longitude, mysql-8.0

I have a table called `place`:

```
id | name       | coordinates (longitude, latitude)
1  | London     | -0.12574, 51.50853
2  | Manchester | -2.25, 53.41667
3  | Glasgow    | -4.25, 55.86667
```

The `coordinates` column is of the **point datatype**. I inserted the points into the `place` table using:

```
st_geomfromtext('point($longitude $latitude)', 4326)
```

Notice that I've made use of the SRID.

Given any coordinates, I'd like to find the nearest places to it (order by ascending). The solution I have currently come up with (by reading the MySQL docs) looks like this:

```
select
    *,
    st_distance_sphere(`place`.`coordinates`, st_geomfromtext('Point($longitude $latitude)', 4326)) as distance
from place
order by distance asc;
```

After looking at countless similar questions on here and elsewhere, it's quite obvious that this is a lesser known (and newer way) of doing things so there's not much content on this, hence why I'm looking for a bit of clarification.

My questions are:

1. Is this the best solution / Am I doing this right?
2. Will this method make use of the spatial index I have on the `coordinates` column?
3. When using [st_distance_sphere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere), do I need to specify the radius of the Earth in order to get accurate results? (Edit: no, it uses the radius of the earth by default)

**Edit, here are those answers:**

`explain select ...;` returns:

```
id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | filtered | Extra
1  | SIMPLE      | place | NULL       | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 115687 | 100.00   | Using filesort
```

`flush status; select ...; show session status like 'Handler%';` returns:

```
Variable_name              | Value
Handler_commit             | 1
Handler_delete             | 0
Handler_discover           | 0
Handler_external_lock      | 2
Handler_mrr_init           | 0
Handler_prepare            | 0
Handler_read_first         | 1
Handler_read_key           | 1001
Handler_read_last          | 0
Handler_read_next          | 0
Handler_read_prev          | 0
Handler_read_rnd           | 1000
Handler_read_rnd_next      | 119395
Handler_rollback           | 0
Handler_savepoint          | 0
Handler_savepoint_rollback | 0
Handler_update             | 0
Handler_write              | 0
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39338167/sql-query-of-haversine-formula-in-sql-server#answer-39338205

Comment: That question is for sql-server and the answers either reflect that or recommend using the haversine formula.

Comment: Nearest places using lat/long pretty much require the haversine formula. SQL Server pretty much is the same as Mysql in terms of syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately sql-server is very different in this instance. Years ago that was true, haversine was the only way to go but if you do some digging, you'll see a whole new slew of functions have been introduced to MySQL that help with storing and querying spatial points/polygons/etc.

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? This is relevant because newer versions offer more complete `st_...` functions.

Comment: @O. Jones Thanks for pointing that out. I'm using the latest version, MySQL 8.0.11.

Comment: @MattKieran you are probably among the first SO people to use the MySQL 8 geospatial stuff.

Comment: MySQL 5.7.6 added `ST_Distance_Sphere()`.

Comment: @MattKieran - The Show, etc, belong to you; moving them out of my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *may* be the best solution.  Let's get some other answers first...

What does `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` say?  (This may answer your Q2).

Your query will scan the entire table, regardless of the other answers.  Perhaps you want `LIMIT ...` on the end?

Another thing that might be useful (depending on your app and on the Optimizer):  Add a bounding box to the `WHERE` clause.

In any case, do the following to get an accurate feel for how many rows are actually touched:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...;
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

Get back with those answers; then perhaps we can iterate further.

**After SHOW STATUS**

Well, `Handler_read_rnd_next` says that it was a full table scan.  The 1000 and 1001 -- did you have `LIMIT 1000`?

I deduce that `LIMIT` is not factored into how `SPATIAL` works.  That is, it does the simplistic thing -- (1) check all rows, (2) sort, (3) `LIMIT`.

So, what to do?

Plan A:  Decide that you don't want results farther than X miles (km) and add a "bounding box" to the query.

Plan B:  Abandon Spatial and dig into a more complex way to do the task:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng