# mysql: using st_distance_sphere giving OK but no results

Tags: mysql, gis, spatial

I have table areas with column id, name, position. The column position is of POINT type and stores (latitude, longitude) of the place.

I read a solution to find nearest places using point datatype and st_distance_sphere in MySQL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50438381/finding-nearest-places-using-point-datatype-and-st-distance-sphere-in-mysql-8). But when I run following query in mysql workbench, i get message: OK. I want to see all the rows that match this criteria.

```
select
    id,name,
    st_distance_sphere(`position`, st_geomfromtext('Point(77.058210 28.632955)', 4326)) as distance
from areas
order by distance asc;
```

Comment: Please reference where you found this so we can look at your base information that should include SHOW CREATE TABLE xxxx.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to check how you construct POINT. POINT constructor has longitude as first parameter.

```
POINT(longitude, latitude)
```

If you have it reversed then you won't get any result since it can't be calculated.
However the query itself is not wrong hence the return message OK.