# MariaDB and MySQL POINT type: In which order are Latitude and Longitude returned?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb, geospatial

When using geospatial column types such as `POINT` with MySQL and MariaDB, there is a lot of confusion about the order in which one should specify latitude and longitude ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11082696/lon-lat-order-when-using-spatial-point-type-with-mysql),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51148381/mysql-using-st-distance-sphere-giving-ok-but-no-results?rq=1),[3](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/axis-order-in-spatial-reference-systems/)), and different applications use different conventions. However, when using some functions - such as `ST_DISTANCE_SPHERE` - the order of lat and long matters.

## In what order to specify Latitude and Longitude when creating a POINT in MySQL and MariaDB?

I slighted adapted an example from the MariaDB docs and tested this on MariaDB 10.6.7 and MySQL 8.0.28. Both databases return numerically identical results:

```
set @zenica   = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(17.907743 44.203438)');
set @sarajevo = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(18.413076 43.856258)');


set @zenica2   = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(44.203438 17.907743)');
set @sarajevo2 = ST_GeomFromText('POINT(43.856258 18.413076)');
SELECT ST_Distance_Sphere(@zenica, @sarajevo), ST_Distance_Sphere(@zenica2, @sarajevo2);
-- Result: 55878.59337591705    67103.51207765185
```

**So in both MySQL and MariaDB, we should put long-lat format when creating POINTS, i.e. longitude goes first**

## In what order do MySQL and MariaDB return GIS coordinates?

When SELECTing a point, MySQL and MariaDB return a binary format of the point. However, I get a different response depending on which database I am using:

```
$testCase = DB::select("SELECT ST_PointFromText('POINT(24.00 12.00)', 4326) AS samplePoint")[0];
$testUnpacked = unpack("lSRID/CByteOrder/lTypeInfo/dFirst/dSecond", $testCase->samplePoint);
var_dump($testUnpacked['First'])
# double(12) -- MySQL output
# double(24) -- MariaDB output
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL the interpretation depends on SRID you use with the data, and follows the SRID-defined order, thus latitude-longitude for SRID 4326. Without SRID (same as SRID=0) it uses longitude-latitude order. It is easy to check by e.g. passing location at the pole, 90:100 - with lat:lon order it is North pole, with lon:lat order it is incorrect data since latitude should be between -90 and 90.

In MySQL you can also use regular `ST_Distance` to compute distance (in meters) between points in SRID=4326, as it properly implements this geographic SRID:

```
-- MySQL 8.0
select 
-- ST_Distance_Sphere without SRID => lon lat order.
st_distance_sphere(
  st_geomfromtext('point(1 90)'),
  st_geomfromtext('point(100 90)')) AS dist_sphere_0,
-- ST_Distance with SRID => lat lon order.  
st_distance(
  st_geomfromtext('point(90 1)', 4326),
  st_geomfromtext('point(90 100)', 4326)) AS dist,
-- ST_Distance_Sphere with SRID => lat lon order.  
st_distance_sphere(
  st_geomfromtext('point(90 1)', 4326),
  st_geomfromtext('point(90 100)', 4326)) AS dist_sphere_4326;
```

All these return 0 or value very close to 0, since all these points have latitude 90 and describe North Pole.

MariaDB does not implement geographic SRID AFAIK, thus it allows any x/y values, ST_Distance still returns incorrect (planar) distance even with SRID=4326, and the order for `ST_Distance_Sphere` always seem to be longitude-latitude.