# Query N closest database entries using active record query interface

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, geospatial

In my Rails project I have a table called "items", where each item has a latitude and longitude property.
When I retrieve the items for my client, I fetch the current user's longitude and latitude. Using these two sets of coordinates, I want to use a haversine function and fetch 100 results with the smallest haversine distance.

The SQL should look something like this:

```
SELECT
*,
haversine_distance(user_lat, user_long, item_lat, item_long) as distance
FROM
db.items
WHERE
item_lat < {user_lat} +1
AND item_lat > {user_lat}+1
AND ..
AND ..
ORDER BY distance DESC
LIMIT 100
```

but this would necessitate using a custom function in the query, which I'm not sure how to do.
Also, regarding lines 7 and 8 of the query, I'm attempting to a where clause to quickly filter the set of results within some reasonable distance so I don't have to apply the haversine to the entire table.
Right now, I have the function defined in a singleton called DistanceService, but I assume I cannot use Ruby functions in the query.

When I tried to add the function `haversine_distance` to the controller and call it like:

```
      @items = Item.select("items.*, haversine_distance(geo_long, geo_lat,
                                  #{@current_user.geo_long}, #{@current_user.geo_lat}) AS distance")
                   .where(status: 'available', ....)
```

I was met with
`FUNCTION ****_api_development.haversine_distance does not exist`. This leads me to think the function should be somehow defined in SQL first via some migration, but I'm not very familiar with SQL and don't know how I would do that with a migration.

I'm also wondering if there's a solution that would support pagination, as it will hopefully eventually become a requirement for my project.

Thanks.

Comment: this link from SO probably can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/39338205/938947

Comment: This will work, but I'm wondering if there's a cleaner way that doesn't require literal SQL, that can be built on top of active record query interface.

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I’m using MySQL specifically InnoDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rails you define database functions through migrations:

```
class AddHaversineDistanceFunction < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<~SQL
      DELIMITER $$
      DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS haversine_distance$$

      CREATE FUNCTION haversine_distance(
        lat1 FLOAT, lon1 FLOAT,
        lat2 FLOAT, lon2 FLOAT
      ) RETURNS FLOAT
      NO SQL DETERMINISTIC
      COMMENT 'Returns the distance in km
             between two known points of latitude and longitude'
      BEGIN
      RETURN DEGREES(ACOS(
        COS(RADIANS(lat1)) *
        COS(RADIANS(lat2)) *
        COS(RADIANS(lon2) - RADIANS(lon1)) +
        SIN(RADIANS(lat1)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat2))
      )) * 111.045;
      END$$

      DELIMITER;
    SQL
  end

  def down
    execute "DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS haversine_distance"
  end
end
```

The actual function here is adapted from [Plum Island Media](https://www.plumislandmedia.net/mysql/stored-function-haversine-distance-computation/).

But you might want to check out the [geocoder gem](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) which provides this functionality and uses a better formula.

Comment: Thanks, can't believe how to add a function via migration.